# Relation between Features & Polynomial Equations in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, features

In Machine Learning, if the data we are working on has, say, 6 features/variables, does that mean the prediction line/curve of our ML model is represented by a Hexic polynomial equation whose degree is 6?

In short, is the degree of our prediction line/curve the same as the number of features in our data?

Comment: How, exactly, do you define "feature" and "variable"?

Comment: Features/variables are the dependent & independent variables of the data.